# How to ONLY print the number that is being produced from du -sh /home?

Tags: text-processing, disk-usage

I wanted to know how to ONLY print the number that is being produced from: `du -sh /home`
because if I execute that command it will print:

```
44M /home
```

I only want the `44M` part to be printed. I want this command to be executed in both Linux and Solaris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `awk`, so you don't need to use the ctrl key:

```
du -sh /home | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this

```
du -sh /home | cut -d" " -f1
```

You insert the space between the two quotes by typing cntl+v then a tab.

Comment: I didn't know about this ctrl+v trick, +1.

Comment: Tab is the default delimiter for `cut`, so `cut -f1` is enough.